# How to run a hive query with a column value equals select of some other query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two huge tables in hive and i have a to run a query of this sort: Example query:

```
    select
    employee_id,
    employee_name,
    employee_address,
    employee_join_date
    employee_travel_pincodes
    from employee
    where 
    employee_join_date = (select join-date from hr_records)
    and
    employee_travel_pincodes in (select _pincodes from hr_records) //returns     multiple records
```

What is best way to achieve this in hive, I can use a subquery but looks like it wont be the cleanest way to achieve the desired output
I am using hive 0.13

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a JOIN for a better performance:

```
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    employee_name,
    employee_address,
    employee_join_date
    employee_travel_pincodes
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN hr_records hr
    ON e.employee_join_date = hr.join-date
    AND e.employee_travel_pincodes = hr._pincodes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left semi join which can be used in Hive in place of:

```
select * from table1 where columnx in (select column x from table2);
```

This is equivelent to a left semi join:

```
 select columnx from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.columnx=b.columnx;
```

Therefore I would use based on the description of your desired query:

```
select
  employee_id,
  employee_name,
  employee_address,
  employee_join_date
  employee_travel_pincodes
from employee a
left semi join hr_records b on a.employee_travel_pincodes=b._pincodes
where a.employee_join_date=b.join-date
;
```